# UITapGesture is not firing

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am loading `FrontViewController`s view into my current view controller `MyVideosViewController`.

I have added 2 notification observers to my `MyVideosViewController` viewdidload()

```
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MyVideosViewController.playLatestvideoClick), name: latestKey, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MyVideosViewController.playMostWatchedvideoClick), name: mostKey, object: nil)
```

in my  `FrontViewController`

```
 //MARK: -Gesture Play
func playLatestvideoClick(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
   print("----- PLAY GESTURE TAPPED ------")
    let imgVw = sender.view as! UIImageView
    api.selectedVideoID = String(imgVw.tag)
    let homeviewcontroller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MYVIDEO") as? MyVideosViewController

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(self.latestKey, object: nil)
}

func playMostWatchedvideoClick(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    print("----- PLAY GESTURE TAPPED ------")
    let imgVw = sender.view as! UIImageView
    api.selectedVideoID = String(imgVw.tag)
    let homeviewcontroller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MYVIDEO") as? MyVideosViewController

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(self.mostKey, object: nil)
}
```

This is how I set thegesture action in `FrontViewController`

```
let tapPlay = UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: (#selector(FrontViewController.playLatestvideoClick(_:))))
        self.imgVideo.addGestureRecognizer(tapPlay)
        self.imgVideo.userInteractionEnabled=true
```

But any of these methods are not firing when I tap the gesture. Whats the reason for this?
Please help me.

**UPDATE**

Its like this. if I reload this MyVideoViewController it works for 1st time. then its not working

Comment: `let tapPlay = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("playLatestvideoClick:")) `  Please try with this

Comment: @EktaMakadiya OP uses swift 2.2 or greater so this will not work.

Comment: Its like this. if I reload this MyVideoViewController it works for 1st time. then its not working

Answer (score 0):

Please try like below code:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MyVideosViewController.playLatestvideoClick(_:)), name: latestKey, object: nil)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MyVideosViewController.playMostWatchedvideoClick(_:)), name: mostKey, object: nil)
```

You need to pass sender like this `(_:)` then it will call this method.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This is wrong answer. He didn't show us those selectors, they are in `MyVideosViewController` class, so seems to be right, also problem occurs erlier in gesture.

Comment: My gesture tap method also not firing,,

Comment: I think you should write it like `UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(FrontViewController.playLatestvideoClick(_:)))`

Comment: let tapPlay = UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: (#selector(FrontViewController.playLatestvideoClick(_:)))) thats how I have written in

Comment: I tried,, still same. it worked first time(The way I have written) and after that nothing happens